# Resizing an image with jquery - delay and move

Tags: jquery, image, resize

```
var hover_effect;
$(document).on("hover", ".card", function (evt) {
    windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var pos = offset.left;

    if (windowWidth - pos < 350) {
        if (evt.type === "mouseenter") {
            hover_effect = setTimeout(function(){
                $('#'+id).css('z-index', '9').animate({
                    marginLeft: '-120',
                    width: '360px',
                    height: '510px'
                }, 300);
            } , 700);
            } 
        else { // mouseleave
            clearTimeout(hover_effect);
            $('#'+id).animate({
                marginLeft: '0',
                width: '240px',
                height: '340px'
            }, 300, function() {
                $('#'+id).css('z-index', '1')
            })
        }
    }
    else if (pos < 260) {
        if (evt.type === "mouseenter") {
            hover_effect = setTimeout(function(){
                $('#'+id).css('z-index', '9').animate({
                    width: '360px',
                    height: '510px'
                }, 300);
            } , 700);
            } 
        else { // mouseleave
            clearTimeout(hover_effect);
            $('#'+id).animate({
                width: '240px',
                height: '340px'
            }, 300, function() {
                $('#'+id).css('z-index', '1')
            })
        }
    }
    else{
        if (evt.type === "mouseenter") {
            hover_effect = setTimeout(function(){
                $('#'+id).css('z-index', '9').animate({
                    marginLeft: '-60',
                    width: '360px',
                    height: '510px'
                }, 300);
            } , 700);
            } 
        else { // mouseleave
            clearTimeout(hover_effect);
            $('#'+id).animate({
                marginLeft: '0',
                width: '240px',
                height: '340px'
            }, 300, function() {
                $('#'+id).css('z-index', '1')
            })
        }
    }
})
```

This checks to see if an image is in the middle of the page, or the right or left, then blows it up accordingly.  `.on` can only return one action, so the `if else` is needed to return each action.  I also used the callback function on the `.css` so that the image wouldn't go "flat" until it had shrunk completely.  Feel free to check it out at http://magic.cardbinder.com/

Thanks Ghosh!

Comment: I'm updating my original code in the question to show the actual answer.  Ghosh was almost correct (the `setTimeout` is definitely correct).  The way .on works, I had to do some finagling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it can be done in a more simplier way.

Try something like this .....

http://jsfiddle.net/35vYZ/

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="pics"></div>
<div class="pics"></div>
<div class="pics"></div>
<div class="pics"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.pics {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background: blue;
float: left;
margin: 5px;
}
.wrapper {
overflow: auto;
background: green;
float: left;
}​
```

Jquery

```
var hover_effect;
$('.pics').hover( function(){
var pics = $(this);
hover_effect = setTimeout(function(){pics.animate({'width' : '60px', 'height' : '60px'}, 300);} , 500);
     }, 
     function(){
         clearTimeout(hover_effect);
         $(this).animate({'width' : '50px', 'height' : '50px'}, {duration: '300', queue: false});
      });
```

​

Comment: I like how that works in your example.  I have a bit of an issue though.  Because I'm using AJAX to bring in cards on the fly, I need to use `.on` or `.live`.  Implementing your code into that gives me an 'unexpected token function' before the cleartimeout section.

Comment: in your modified code the eventObject is missing...
    $(document).on("hover", ".card", function (evt) {...};

correct it then look for further errors using firebug

Comment: EVT is undefined.  I'm still learning this stuff, so I'm not sure where I'm supposed to define that.